# Get running 'days since first occurence' per user_id in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem I am trying to find a clever solution for in Pandas. I know how to make it work in Excel but am struggling in Python.

Imagine the following data

| user_id | date |
| --- | --- |
| user1 | 2020-01-01 |
| user1 | 2020-01-02 |
| user1 | 2020-01-05 |
| user1 | 2020-01-07 |
| user2 | 2020-01-01 |
| user2 | 2020-01-03 |
| user2 | 2020-01-04 |

I want a column `days since first occurrence` as follows:

| user_id | date | days_since_first_occurence |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user1 | 2020-01-01 | 0 |
| user1 | 2020-01-02 | 1 |
| user1 | 2020-01-05 | 4 |
| user1 | 2020-01-07 | 6 |
| user2 | 2020-01-01 | 0 |
| user2 | 2020-01-03 | 2 |
| user2 | 2020-01-04 | 3 |

What would be the most efficient way to get this? I need the calc to be individual for each user id

Comment: `df['date']-df['date'].iloc[0]` or is `user_id ` important? Do you want to group on `user_id `?

Comment: Yes! I need this to be on a user_id basis. Basically I want to get rid of the dates and be able to compare "days since first activity" between users instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
df["days_since_first_occurence"] = (df["date"]-df.groupby("user_id")["date"].transform("min")).dt.days

>>> df
  user_id       date  days_since_first_occurence
0   user1 2020-01-01                           0
1   user1 2020-01-02                           1
2   user1 2020-01-05                           4
3   user1 2020-01-07                           6
4   user2 2020-01-01                           0
5   user2 2020-01-03                           2
6   user2 2020-01-04                           3
```

Comment: all three very helpful answers cam simultaneously - yours was the most elaborate/general so I am accepting this one! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Groupby and transform the first value in the group then subtract

```
df['days_since_first_occurence'] = df['date'] - df.groupby('user_id')['date'].transform('first')

  user_id       date days_since_first_occurence
0   user1 2020-01-01                     0 days
1   user1 2020-01-02                     1 days
2   user1 2020-01-05                     4 days
3   user1 2020-01-07                     6 days
4   user2 2020-01-01                     0 days
5   user2 2020-01-03                     2 days
6   user2 2020-01-04                     3 days
```

Comment: Why not `min` instead of `first`?

Comment: @not_speshal assumes dates were sorted.

Comment: `first` answers better than `min` as the question says `days since first occurrence` rather than  `days since earliest date (minimum value)`.   Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

```
  df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
  df['days_since_first_occurence'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['date'] - df[df['user_id'] == x['user_id']].iloc[0]['date'],axis=1)
```

Comment: You should use `min` instead of `iloc[0]`. Otherwise you're implicitly assuming that the data is sorted.

Comment: FYI whenever you see these to characters together ("][") in pandas, you are more than likely chained indexing.  
Chained indexing(https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy) should be avoided in most cases.